# opening file in cpp to run on emscripten

Tags: c++, emscripten

Trying to open .hex file on cpp that has to be run on emscripten, it shows error in opening files. tried to import the files using --preload-file (emscripten) but still it shows problem in opening the files.

Comment: Can you include a minimal example of code that shows what you're doing, and post the errors that occur?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use XMLHttpRequest to get the file in the JavaScript side and deliver the data to the C++ side as an byte array.

Something like this:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emscripten-discuss/PeywyNHBbmY

I have used embind to bind my C++ API to the JavaScript side:
http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html